# Ionic Android Build Error

Tags: android, ionic-framework

[image]

I am getting the following errors when building Android with the Ionic CLI.

The first error says "Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:+."

I have tried updating all the Android API's but still have the same errors.
I think there is a simple solution but I am just not familiar with Android and the SDK Manager, so attached is also a screenshot of what I have download using the SDK Manager. Am I missing anything?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try with removing existing platforms and plugins and add them again

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after going into the pits of hell, I managed to fix this. Disclaimer: I am very new to building/compiling for Android (remember, I'm an Ionic user and we want nothing to do with the hurdles of working with native Android/iOS) and so this solution may seem pretty obvious.

SOLUTION (WINDOWS 7):

- I had a very old version of Android Studio - I upgraded. Even though the old SDK Manager said all API's were downloaded and fine, I guess it was so outdated (from 2014 I think) that it was misleading me with false flags.
- System Paths are a mess. Some people tell you to point to the 'appData' location of the Android SDK, and others tell you to point to the 'AndroidSDK' folder on your C drive. The 'appData' location ended up working for me.

  - **SYSTEM PATH INSTRUCTIONS:**
  - Go to Control Panel > Advanced System Settings > 'Advanced' tab in the System Properties popup > Environment Variables.
  - Now set a new 'SYSTEM' variable and call it ANDROID_HOME and give it the following value: `C:\Users\<YOUR_USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk`
  - Finally, in the SYSTEM VARIABLES section, update 'Path' (DO NOT COMPLETELY REPLACE, just add the following text to it) with `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;`
  - Now save system variables, hit okay (exit all those popups), then close and reopen your terminal (I am using GIT Bash). Run your Cordova/Ionic Android build command again and it should work `cordova build --release android`